# Retrieving data from WebMethod using Jquery Ajax in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have jquery variable which contains following value ..

```
var data = [['Vikas', 75], ['Sumit', 55], ['Rakesh', 96], ['Shivam', 123], ['Kapil', 34], ['Rana', 104]];
```

Now as per my requirement i need those values from server side code,for this i have written a webmethod in c#.

```
[WebMethod()]
public List<string> getData()
{
    List<string> dbdata = new List<string>();

    dbdata.Add("Vikas,200");
    dbdata.Add("Sumit,120");
    dbdata.Add("Rakesh,200");
    dbdata.Add("Shivam,500");
    dbdata.Add("Kapil,234");
    dbdata.Add("Rana,104");

    return dbdata;
}
```

But this is not the correct format of the data what is there in local data.

Here is my jquery ajax request..

```
               $("#getdata").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService2.asmx/getData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (dbdata) {
                        //data = JSON.parse(dbdata);
                        data = dbdata;
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

My webMethod response ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d1p1:type="q1:string"   xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">["LOCAL,200","STD,120","ISD,200","VOIP,500","INCOMING,234","INET,104"]</anyType>
```

Comment: Do you want the result of `getData` as a json object?

Comment: @DGibbs i want this to be in var data = [['Vikas', 75], ['Sumit', 55], ['Rakesh', 96], ['Shivam', 123], ['Kapil', 34], ['Rana', 104]]; format

Comment: First of all you are not returning JSON data from web method. And the "data" is also not JSON. First make sure that they are JSON after that perform operations you want

Comment: @DGibbs yes sir i want the result of getdata as a json object

Comment: @PrabhatJain Sir i want webmethod data to return data in this format\ var data = [['Vikas', 75], ['Sumit', 55], ['Rakesh', 96], ['Shivam', 123], ['Kapil', 34], ['Rana', 104]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to return a json object from the `getData` method then I recommend using the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library and modifying the method to return an `object`:

```
[WebMethod()]
public object getData()
{
   List<string> dbdata = new List<string>();

   dbdata.Add("Vikas,200");
   dbdata.Add("Sumit,120");
   dbdata.Add("Rakesh,200");
   dbdata.Add("Shivam,500");
   dbdata.Add("Kapil,234");
   dbdata.Add("Rana,104");

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbdata);
}
```

Comment: Sir please see my updated post for response that i am getting from server.Sir how can i use my object values here

Comment: You would use the response data in the `success` function of your ajax call. I'm not sure what you intend to do with the values but they should be contained in the `dbdata` object in this method.

Comment: Sir i am not getting alert message in success function why?

Comment: You probably have a javascript error of some sort. Check in your browsers console window.

Comment: I am not getting any error on console ..Here is my sucess code..success: function (dbdata) {
                            //data = JSON.parse(dbdata.d);
                            alert(dbdata);
                            console.log(dbdata);
                        }

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.parse` as the data has already been converted to json

Comment: What happens when you call `alert(dbdata);`? Have you tried doing `alert(dbdata.d);`? The `dbdata` variable is your json object. What exactly do you intend to do with the result? Your OP only asks how to return JSON from the webmethod, if you have another question you should start a new thread.

Comment: no alert box comes ..I tried alert(dbdata.d); still same result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365813/data-recieved-from-webservice-is-not-showing-in-alert-box-by-using-jquery-ajax/23365956#23365956   Please see my new thread

Comment: Try adding the `contentType` to the `ajax` POST. e.g `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. This works for me.